# Excess "empty" matches using regular expressions

Tags: regex

Here's regex - `((?:\-\s*)?(?:\d*){1})(?=x1?(?!\d))`. I have a problem with **\d***

---

I need to solve task of finding math equations (like x2, x)

For example i have text: **9278x2 - 3040x + 0x1 - x2 + 3x + x**

As result (of finding x coefficient) i should get: "- 3040", "0", "3", "".

**""** here for x, because x don't have coefficient, but it means that there is 1x

---

Hovewer, usind `\d*` instead of `\d+` **(because regex will not find "" of x)**, i also get an excess matches of ""

**Correct matches should be with just one regex and be in first group**, this is a condition of this task, soo... how this can be solved?
[image]

Comment: Instead of screenshot, provide link to regex101.

Comment: Try `(?<!\d)((?:-\s*)?\d*)(?=x1?(?!\d))`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5uiFF0/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - it works! thanks!

Comment: Please see my answer below and pay attention to the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict a match if it is immediately preceded with a digit:

```
((?:-\s*)?(?<!\d)\d*)(?=x1?(?!\d))
          ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kA7XnG/2/)

**Details**

- `((?:-\s*)?(?<!\d)\d*)` - Group 1 (it looks redundant though, you may remove the outer parentheses unless you need to do something special):

  - `(?:-\s*)?` - an optional sequence of `-` and 0+ whitespace chars
  - `(?<!\d)` - no digit is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `(?=x1?(?!\d))` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is `x` followed with an optional `1` and that is not followed with a digit. Note you probably need to use `1?+` to make sure your negative lookahead gets executed once and only after `1` is matched if it is there).